# Ruby source filename clash with `require`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

What is the correct way to deal with identically named ruby source files and ensuring the correct file is loaded by a given `require` statement?

## Background

I want to make use of the [ruby-geometry](https://github.com/DanielVartanov/ruby-geometry) gem in my Rails 3 app.

I'm attempting to make use of the ruby-geometry `Polygon` class:

```
require 'geometry'  # the main ruby-geometry gem file

module SomeModule
    def SomeMethod(vertices)
        polygon = Geometry::Polygon.new(vertices)
        
        # Do some stuff with polygon...
    end
end
```

However, whenever I attempt to run this code I get the following error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Geometry::Polygon`

This is strange because I seem to be able to work with any of the other ruby-geometry classes without a problem (e.g. `Geometry::Point`, `Geometry::Segment`).

## The Problem

The problem is that my app contains a source file named `polygon.rb` (contains an ActiveRecord model) and [so does the ruby-geometry gem](https://github.com/DanielVartanov/ruby-geometry/blob/master/lib/polygon.rb). So when the ruby-geometry gem [`require`s its own `polygon.rb`](https://github.com/DanielVartanov/ruby-geometry/blob/master/lib/geometry.rb#L7) it ends up loading my app's `polygon.rb` instead. Presumably this is all down to the order in which ruby searches through directories.

What is the "proper" approach to resolving this naming clash?

Obviously *within code* you can use modules to differentiate between namespaces to resolve class name clashes. Is there a simple way to differentiate between identically-named source files when `require`-ing them?

Comment: Can't you rename your code file? Why is this not an option? That would be the simplest way to do it. Rename it `polygon_record.rb` or something like that.

Comment: Agreed that is an option, it just seems like doing this is an admission that the `require` mechanism is broken. I should be able to name source files however I wish without having to ensure that the name does not clash with any of the source files in the n gems my app depends on. Plus, what if the clash is between source files in two gems (which I can't easily rename)? I can't believe there isn't a better solution.

Comment: i guess that if you really don't want to rename your model, you can always require the file with an absolute path, though i won't recommend it

Comment: @tomtheguvnor: I agree. There must be a better solution. But `require`s and gems have never been a very clear or good area of Ruby where more things are hacked then done right. The gem should be using the gem environment and then appending something like `lib/ruby-geometry/polygon.rb`. That would ensure that it loads it's own library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is an error in the *geometry* gem implementation. It is relying in the `$LOAD_PATH` environment variable to decide where its requested files are. I rather would prefer to use `require_relative` or using the `File.dirname(__FILE__)` value to require relative path files in my gems.

For solving your issue you can *require* the geometry gem before *Rails* is adding its own paths to the `$LOAD_PATH` environment variable.

One way to do this that has worked to me is explicitly require this gem in the `GEMFILE`:

```
gem "ruby-geometry", :require => "geometry"
```

Another way would be to remove your `app/models` path from the `$LOAD_PATH` array before require the *geometry* gem:

```
old_load_path = $LOAD_PATH
$LOAD_PATH.delete(File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/app/models"))
require "geometry"
$LOAD_PATH.replace(old_load_path)
```

But this is ugly as hell.

Comment: Thanks. Your Gemfile hack did the trick. I'll see about creating a fix for gem and send through a pull request.